# How to make videos play in safari browser?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The issue is that the Safari browser won't play videos uploaded into blob storage like aws. How to make those videos play without changing the server?

Comment: What errors do you see?  How are you attempting to play the videos?  What is AWS Blob Storage?

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)